# Linq Custom sorting in ORDER BY and rest of result order by asc

Tags: vb.net, linq

I have a list of string with companyNames,

```
1. CompanyA
2. CompanyB
3. CompanyA
4. CompanyC
```

My approach is:

```
 Dim companyNames = From cp In companyList 
                    Order By If(cp.CompanyName = 'CompanyC', 1, 0) Descending
                    Select cp.CompanyName
                    Distinct
```

But i got result :

```
1. CompanyC
1. CompanyB
2. CompanyA
```

I want to keep order by companyName Order before set "CompanyC" as first.
, i want the follow result

```
 1. CompanyC
 2. CompanyA
 3. CompanyB
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand what you what at all. you want to have the original order and only put `CompanyC` as the first element?

Comment: @pikoh i want to order asc alphabetic, before companyC

Comment: Then why don't you order all the list ascending, and then move `CompanyC` to the first index? I think that would be a lot more simple

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need another order by `CompanyName Ascending`:

```
Dim companyNames = 
    From cp In companyList 
    Order By If(cp.CompanyName = "CompanyC", 1, 0) Descending, CompanyName Ascending
    Select cp.CompanyName
    Distinct
```